# Java: Arranging 2-D Array Neatly

Tags: java, arrays

How can I arrange the following 2-D array horizontally for each of the 3 elements within each element? ...let me demonstrate to make it more clear:

Using the for loop...

```
  String[][] myArray = {{"x","   y","   z"}, {"x", "  y",...

  for (x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
     for (y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
        System.out.println(myArray[x][y]);
     }
  }
```

this is my current output...

```
  x
  y
  z
```

if i use `System.out.print()`, I get...

```
  xyzxyzxyzxyz
```

Ultimately, I want this...

```
  x   y   z
  x   y   z
```

Any help?

Comment: Why would you have space before elements in array when you can achieve same while printing

Comment: If you utterly want this just use a tab with `System.our.print()` or within with `println()`.

Comment: the "\t" will do, if I knew it existed, I would have used that instead

Answer (score 2):

change your for loop to this

```
for (x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
     for (y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
        System.out.print(sortByDesc[x][y]+"\t");
     }
        System.out.println("");
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The outside `for` loop can function as your line break..

```
for (x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
 for (y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
    System.out.print(sortByDesc[x][y]);
 }
 System.out.println();
}
```

This will yield..

```
xyz
xyz
xyz
```

Then, you simply print a `\t` char after them.

```
for (x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
 for (y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
    System.out.println(sortByDesc[x][y] + "\t");
 }
 System.out.println();
}
```

**IDEOne:** http://ideone.com/1Y08kU

Comment: check your code . you have println there System.out.println(sortByDesc[x][y]);

Comment: `println()` -> `print()`

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :-

```
String[][] myArray = {{"x","y","z"}, {"x", "y","z"}};

for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
   for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
      System.out.print(myArray[x][y]+"\t");
   }
   System.out.println("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[][] myArray = {{"x","   y","   z"}, {"x", "  y",...

  for (x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
     for (y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
        System.out.print(sortByDesc[x][y]+" ");
     }
   if((x+1)%3==0)
      System.out.println("");
  }
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer? (Flagged as low quality by SO)

Comment: You only need a newline after when you have done with printing 3 characters and 3 spaces, as x = 0 (initializing from zero) so every (x+1)%3 == 0 will be the state when 3 characters have been already printed for this line,

Comment: @Rico, Can you elaborate why you flag this one as low quality. Keep an eye on above mentioned answers, and compare all ov them honestly,

Comment: @securedeveloper It is often more helpful to provide some explanation to the code snippet so that the person asking the question understands better.